# FC command not finding existing directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

When i run the code, `fc` says that it didnt find any directory like this. This is the point where it it trips over- at the `fc "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car\defaultES2File" "Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File"`. I will add more code if you want, but this is the most important point.

```
:check
echo checking
attrib "data.txt" -h
pause
fc "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car\defaultES2File" "Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File"
pause
```

Here is a proof that the directory exists
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kp02bvZu9XA-sV2wD8HQWUfKUIuJUfrj/view?usp=sharing

And here is the console output. I dont know why but it displays it in caps, i dont know if it matters.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WXzosPaMY5GD0KcBg74ZvOzX0sgeZHXV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To begin with, I'm not logging into Google in order to see images which could easily have been hosted using this site's recommended host and method. Also you've only provided a small snippet, so we have no idea what `%curdt%` is resolving to. Additionally are you sure that your file names do not have extensions? because I'm sure it should be a text file with a `.txt` extension, `defaultES2File.txt`. I would advise everybody to **always uncheck the `Hide extensions for known file types` check box in their Windows Explorer settings**, so that they're fully aware of what every file extension is.

Comment: Ok. About pictures, the site doesnt let me upload. It says i need bigger reputation. and now i see my mistake after hour of looking.... I forgot to put .txt. Thank you

Comment: No worries, but it wouldn't have taken much, even without removing the insecure Explorer setting, to try `dir "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car"`, or better `dir "%UserProfile%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car"` or even better `dir "%AppData%\..\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car"` in a Command Prompt window to see what was in there first! As far as I remember your task is only to copy six text files anyhow, so why you cannot just copy those files with the `copy` command to a directory created using the date and time without using `fc.exe` is beyond me!

Comment: @Compo, "%AppData%\..\LocalLow" is actually worse. "%AppData%" defaults to "%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming", but it can be relocated independent of the user profile directory. OTOH, "AppData\Local" and "AppData\LocalLow" generally are not relocated (and, at least in Windows 10, cannot be relocated using the shell). So one can't assume a common parent directory in this case.

Comment: Yes, I was a little too vague due to comment length restrictions, and should not have used the term `better`, @ErykSun. However, at least one of those three should have provided a view of their files showing the `.txt` file extension, _(and very probably, all of them)_.

Comment: "%UserProfile%" is objectively better than "C:\Users\%UserName%", though it would be uncommon for them to differ.

Comment: The second path in your `fc` command line is relative; use an absolute path too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not using the correct file name.

Your file is a text file and should be named with a `.txt` extension.

```dos
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Amistech\My Summer Car\defaultES2File.txt"
```

In addition to that, I would also advise that you use an absolute path to your backup file in the comparison too. Currently `"Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File"` is relative to the current directory at the time the command is being run. This may be okay if you've specifically changed directory to the correct location beforehand, but it would be safer. At the very least, you could use a variable for the current directory, i.e. `"%CD%\Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File.txt"`, or `"%__CD__%Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File.txt"`. It may even be the case that your backups are going into a location relative to the running batch file, so you could instead use, `"%~dp0Saves\backup_%curdt%\defaultES2File.txt"` to ensure it does, and is not affected by current directory changes.

---

I would advise everybody to always go into their Windows Explorer settings and specifically stop the default hiding of known file extensions. This way they are always informed of what extension each file carries.

In newer versions of Windows, you should be able to do that in the Explorer ribbon, by toggling the check mark against <kbd>File name extensions</kbd> in 'Show/hide' section. In earlier versions of Windows you may need to go into the 'Folder and search options' settings to uncheck the <kbd>Hide extensions for known file types</kbd> check box.